# credit-card payment with split receiver

Tags: payment, credit-card

We are building an Web and mobile app where we need to find a solution for the payment part.

When the end user of the app has decided to pay we would like 10% of the amount to go to our account and the rest should go the the actual service/shop/store that the end user is paying for. I guess this is a quite common requirement but is it possible on any of the current payment service api:s out there. Any recommendation on how to move forward on this is apriciated.

Comment: This is off topic here.  You cannot split a card transaction; you would charge the whole amount then pay the 3rd party from your own account, or have the transaction credit the 3rd party, who you later invoice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Balanced](https://www.balancedpayments.com/) or [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collecting-fees) to achieve this.

Comment: Updated: Balanced is shutting down: https://www.balancedpayments.com/stripe . "Balanced is shutting down and will stop processing credit and debit card charges and ACH debits on June 11, 2015."